# What is the proper way to store a chosen ACAccount for a further use through the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, social-framework

I'm building an app in which the user will use one of his iOS integrated Twitter accounts. I'm using the Accounts Framework and in the [documentation example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Listings/Tweeting_TweetingViewController_m.html), the account from which the request to Twitter will be performed is grabbed this way : `ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];` so the user has no choice regarding which "TWAccount" he is using.

I will easily build an UISheet to display all Twitter accounts and let the user choose the one he wants, but **my question is**:

What is the proper way to store the chosen account for a long term use through the app?

Edit: Sorry my question wasn't entirely clear. I want to store it like we store other preferences for an app. So the first time the user is launching the app he has to chose which account to use, but after that he will never have to chose anymore when he'll relaunch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it like any other object you'd store. It's an object. Retain it. For example, under ARC you'd simply assign it to a property. Remember to register for ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification just in case the user does something, such as deleting this account, behind your back; if the notification arrives, your supposed to release your ACAccount object and fetch it again.

The account is uniquely identified by its `identifier`, so on subsequent launches of your app you can fetch it again with `accountWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Yes but what I want is to store it when the app is shut down to retrieve it when it will be launched again. And so the user doesn't have to chose once again wich TWAccount he wants to use in the UISheet etc...

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I edited my question. This looks great, let me try that !

Comment: The identifier is just a string so you can stick it into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying to myself, thank you very much !